How to produce a view of 3 tables
I'm a new sql user, and I'm trying to create a view of several tables: table_1, table_2, table_3
table_1 contains columns key_id, descrip, sub_descrip. Primary key is (key_id, descrip)
table_2 contains columns key_id, another_id, amount. Primary key is key_id.
table_3 contains columns another_id, amount_mod. Primary key is another_id.
I want to create a view where each row is a distinct key_id (the number of rows in this table should be equal to the number of distinct key_id that exist in BOTH table1 and table2) with the following columns:
descrip_list (this should be a list/array of all descrip for that key_id) from table_1
sub_descrip_list (this should be a list/array of all descrip for that key_id) from table_1
amount (from table_2)
amount_mod (from table_3)

I asked chatgpt to produce the query and it gave:
CREATE VIEW combined_view AS
SELECT 
    t1.key_id,
    t2.another_id,
    t2.amount,
    t3.amount_mod,
    STRING_AGG(t1.descrip, ', ') AS descrips
    STRING_AGG(t1.sub_descrip, ', ') AS sub_descrips
FROM 
    table1 t1
JOIN 
    table2 t2 ON t1.key_id = t2.key_id
JOIN 
    table3 t3 ON t3.another_id = t2.another_id
GROUP BY
    t1.key_id, t2.another_id, t2.amount;

Why is the group by needed here? And if it's needed, it's not clear to me why any grouping by another_id1, amount is needed.

The group by is facilitating the STRING_AGG functions. That creates a comma delimited string where all the entries in the descrip and sub_descrip fields are concatenated. Without the group by the query would fail.
You actually probably want to replace STRING_AGG with ARRAY_AGG since I imagine it's possible that a description can include commas. You might just change the separator to something like a pipe | or another character that doesn't appear in the description.

SELECT CONCAT('Item ', item_number) AS item_description FROM items; thanks, I was thinking this as well. Right now it's not a possibilibty but this table is dynamically rebuilt and it could have commas in the future, so ARRAY_AGG seems more future proof.

re group by. I see, but shouldn't grouping by t1.key_id by itself be sufficient? why is t2.another_id, t2.amount needed?

You need to add every column that is part of the fixed "identity set" - basically any column you are selecting and are not performing an aggregation on.
